# How to set variable if a token = to a given number

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to set a variable if a token=1 or a token=2 and so on.

This is a command line batch file

My question is how do I make my code valid so it adds up all the 1 page pdfs and puts the total number of 1 pagers in a variable called 1sided and 2 pager into a variable called 2sided and so on. I will add the contents of pdfcount.tmp in a second.

See code below for what I have made already:

```
if exist *.zip for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (pdfcount.tmp) do if "%%a"=="[1]" set 1sided=%%a
if exist *.zip for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (pdfcount.tmp) do if "%%a"=="[2]" set 2sided=%%a
if exist *.zip for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (pdfcount.tmp) do if "%%a"=="[3]" set 3sided=%%a
if exist *.zip for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (pdfcount.tmp) do if "%%a"=="[4]" set 4sided=%%a
if exist *.zip for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (pdfcount.tmp) do if "%%a"=="[5]" set 5sided=%%a
```

I found a sample code that might be close to the answer I am looking for:

```
set index=1
for /f "tokens=3*" %%A in (%file%) do (
    if ("%%A"=="Domains") (
        for %%C in (%%B) do (
            set Domain!index!=%%C
            set /A index+=1
        )
    )
)
```

Here is contents of pdfcount.tmp

```
24014-20190201-1-en.pdf, 1 
24163-20190201-1-en.pdf, 1 
24219-20190201-1-en.pdf, 1 
2466-20190201-1-en.pdf, 1 
26946-20190201-1-en.pdf, 2 
27103-20190201-1-en.pdf, 3 
28563-20190201-1-en.pdf, 2 
29019-20190201-1-en.pdf, 2 
29287-20190201-1-en.pdf, 3 
30500-20190201-1-en.pdf, 2 
31401-20190201-1-en.pdf, 3 
31525-20190201-1-en.pdf, 2 
31590-20190201-1-en.pdf, 3 
32445-20190201-1-en.pdf, 3 
3765-20190201-1-en.pdf, 1 
4837-20190201-1-en.pdf, 1 
5083-20190201-1-en.pdf, 1 
756-20190201-1-en.pdf, 2
```

---

Just ran into an issue where it will print a list of the sides and the quantity but puts 11 or 15 or 19 above 2 or 3 probably because 11 starts with a 1.
Need double and triple digit numbers to be placed under single digit numbers.
Here is an example of my issue.

```
Sides_18=1
Sides_3=201
Sides_4=33
Sides_5=4
Sides_6=3
Sides_7=1
Sides_8=1
```

Comment: Could you please provide (a few lines of) `%file%`? Else we have to guess and guesses mostly tend to be wrong. Also I fail to see a connection between the first and second code snippet. Please clarify (or remove unneded parts).

Comment: the code with the %file% is not my code. the 5 lines of code above in the first part is my code. the code on the bottom is just showing how the code could be laid out and might be the layout I am looking for. why do I have a minus 1? I have done nothing wrong. I just asked a question.

Comment: Well, you do not describe what you want to achieve and what you actually get, so please [edit] your question and clarify. Perhaps also the source of your "found sample code" could be useful. Also take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]!

Comment: ok, so a few example lines of `pdfcount.tmp` would be helpful

Comment: my question is how do I make my code valid so it adds up all the 1 page pdfs and puts the total number of 1 pagers in a variable called 1sided. I will add the contents of pdfcount.tmp in a second.

Comment: Ah, didn't I say **[edit]** the question? Regard that comments may be cleaned up later! N. B.: do not define variable names beginning with a digit, let them always begin with a letter or any of `_`, `$`, `#`...

Comment: Sorry, I have modified my post above

Comment: the delimiter is the comma and the 2nd token is the number of pages in that pdf. I am using a command line pdf tool to auto generate that pdfcount.tmp file.

Comment: so I should do "set sides1=%%a" or "set sides2=%%a"  ?

Comment: can the -1 rating be reversed on my question.

Comment: Not sure why this question received a downvote because it is a valid question and meets the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still a bit vague, but my guess would be something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (pdfcount.tmp) do (
  set /a nr=%%a
  set /a Pages_!nr! +=1
)
set pages_
```

**EDIT** to sort the variables, you could just add the following line:

```
for /l %%i in (0,1,300) do if defined pages_%%i echo Pages:%%i=!pages_%%i!
```

(Note: adapt the `300` to a value above max page count)

but a better way is to name the variables sortable in the first place:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (pdfcount.tmp) do (
  set /a nr=%%a+10000
  set /a Pages_!nr:~-4! +=1
)
set pages_
```

Comment: I just added an issue I am having to the bottom of my question above. Thank You